# How to simply express a desire to run a function when two properties are true?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function ($, _, Backbone) {
    'use strict';

    //  TODO: Would like to access through define module, but not sure how..
    var player = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().YouTubePlayer;
    var user = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().User;

    //  If the foreground is opened before the background has had a chance to load, wait for the background.
    //  This is easier than having every control on the foreground guard against the background not existing.
    if (user.get('loaded')) {
        loadForeground();
    } else {
        user.on('change:loaded', function (model, loaded) {
            if (loaded) {
                loadForeground();
            } else {
                //  Show refreshing message?
            }
        });
    }

    function loadForeground() {

        if (player.get('ready')) {
            //  Load foreground when the background indicates it has loaded.
            require(['foreground']);
        } else {

            player.once('change:ready', function () {

                //  Load foreground when the background indicates it has loaded.
                require(['foreground']);
            });
        }

    }
});
```

My goal is to call `require(['foreground'])` once the user object is loaded and the player is ready. This code works fine, but seems really unclear / overly verbose.

Am I missing an easy simplification in trying to express this need?

Answer (score 2):

[`jQuery.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/), or even just [promises in general](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A), would make your code simpler. In short, a promise can be unfulfilled, fulfilled, or failed. [`jQuery.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) lets you compose multiple promises into one promise that's fulfilled when they're all fulfilled or failed as soon as one fails. This means that you can

1. create `Deferred`s for each event you want to monitor:

   ```
   var userLoaded = new $.Deferred();
   var playerReady = new $.Deferred();
   ```
2. Resolve the promises when whatever event they represent has completed, e.g.:

   ```
   userLoaded.resolve();
   ```

   If there's an error, you can signal that if you want as well:

   ```
   userLoaded.reject();
   ```
3. Compose them together:

   ```
   $.when(userLoaded, playerReady).then(function() {
       require(['foreground']);
   });
   ```

   If you pass a second argument to `then`, it will be called if either of the promises are rejected, simplifying error-handling, should you wish to do that.